# Cannot start MIT Scheme - Heap Size exceeded

Tags: windows, scheme, mit-scheme, edwin

For some reason I'm having trouble running MIT scheme. On my Dell, which runs Windows Vista, I can't even open MIT scheme; I get a message: "Heap Size exceeded", or something like that. I can run it fine on my Mac, but Edwin is a bit confusing. Does anyone know how to fix my problem on Windows, and where I can find some good Edwin tutorials? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edwin is a variant of Emacs which uses Scheme instead of Emacs Lisp. Take a look at the relevant sections of the MIT Scheme manual:

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/user_8.html#SEC55

Not sure why MIT Scheme wouldn't run on Windows, however, if you installed it on OS X, try just running `mit-scheme` from Terminal.app. This should just give you a Scheme REPL. You can enter Scheme expressions etc, and also load Scheme source files with `(load "file.scm")`. Finally, you can also load files from the command line with `mit-scheme --load file.scm`.

If all that doesn't work, are you sure you need MIT Scheme? You could try PLT Scheme/Racket, which would let you run Scheme code, you might have better luck in Windows. Not sure about that though.